# Exploding first results

Tags: php

Currently I am working on a project which requires me to explode and replace the first results for various different sequences and one of those sequences is the number scheme for `0-9` which is causing me some issues.

The project is basically removing tracklists numbers, and replacing them with artist names for all varieties of album submissions.

Here's an example of some, and what I've done for the two solutions I have already.

```
01 Song Artist - Song Name
01. Song Artist - Song Name
01. Song Name
01 Song Name
```

So above you see that each result is different in a small way, mostly that the top and the bottom don't contain a period so my method for the **Third**, and **Fourth** one isn't working, here's that method.

```
if (strpos($middle, '-') !== false) {

    // Middle is being loaded outside of this also, I included it here so you could see what it is.

    $middle = $songname;
    list($before, $after) = explode('.', $middle, 2);
    print $after;

    // This code removes the first . in play, and returns only the "Artist Name - Song Name" portion.

} else {

    // The $title string is the name of the album, not the individual songs.

    $middle = $songname;
    list($before, $after) = explode('.', $middle, 2);
    $exp = explode('&#8211;', $title);
    $blimg = $exp[0];
    print $blimg;
    print '-';
    print $after;   

    // This code explodes the first . in an example like "01. Song Name" and returns "Song Name" then we return the first portion of the album title, to collect the artist as well.
}
```

What can I do to continue this pattern, but for the other two variants of titles?

Comment: Why not use an regular expression?  match for numbers for two digits, followed by anything and then a space, then you can also test with an original expression on the 2nd part of the 1st result array for a `-` like you need, and use the second part of that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you would want to standardise the strings before doing anything to them in order to make the check easier.

```
<?php

$possibleFormats = [
    '01 Song Artist - Song Name',
    '01. Song Artist - Song Name',
    '01. Song Name',
    '01 Song Name'
];

$nameArray = [];

foreach ($possibleFormats as $key => $format) {
    // Remove all .
    $format = str_replace(".", "", $format);

    // Remove all numbers
    $format = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $format);

    // Trim whitespace and update $possibleFormats array
    $possibleFormats[$key] = trim($format);

    // Set the value in the song name array
    $nameArray[] = getSongName($format);
}

function getSongName(string $format) : string
{
    if (strpos($format, '-') !== false) {
        $format = explode('-', $format)[1];
    }

    return $format;
}

print_r($nameArray);
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  Much better than my regular expression answer below.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions as I mentioned above.  Here would be one for the numbers with any character and a space following

`([0-9]{2})(.)?(\s)`

You're matching 2 numbers `[0-9]{2}`, followed by 0 or 1 of any character `(.)?`, followed by a space`(\s)`.

Then, I'd explode on the `-`, and if you have one or two results, do a `trim()` of them, and you'll have song title and artist, respectfully.

Comment: The answer above is for sure better then this, however I also really like your answer just because it taught me something I didn't know about. :) Thank you.